# How to Enable/ Disable Render properties of any collection

Tags: rendering, animation

I usually do enable/ disable of rendering by pressing ‘i’ on the ‘camera icon’ beside the required object in ‘Outliner’ during the course of requirement of any Animation Project. However, sometimes it requires to enable/ disable a whole ‘Collection’ in rendering but if I press ‘i’ on the camera icon beside any collection, a message comes that *“hide_render” property cannot be animated*.
Please provide a solution to enable/ disable a whole ‘Collection’ in rendering rather to go by object to object and enable/ disable each one in rendering.
A screenshot is shared.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for proposing the similar question. It seems that there is no single way to solve this problem.